# How to force fragment restart even though parent activity handles onconfigurationchanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am working on an SDK that uses fragments only as overlay. It should support both portrait and landscape modes. That is why I have to support automatic orientation change (activity/fragment restart) and overriding of the `onConfigurationChanged` method. I've managed to handle the first case, but I am wondering how can I force restart the fragment within itself, even though the activity didn't restart on orientation change

Comment: You say you want to support automatic orientation change but then you are handling it manually for activities by overriding onConfigurationChanged. Is there a reason you are not letting the OS just handle orientation change for you? Sometimes it can seem tempting to handle it yourself to solve an issue you are having. But in the long run, it can just cause more issues.

Comment: As I've said, I am working on an SDK that only uses fragments. It is up to the host app developer to decide whether they want to override the configuration change or not in their activities which use this SDK.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense now. If you don't find a good answer, maybe just document your SDK and tell developers not to do that! In my opinion, it's poor activity design if a developer finds themselves manually handling orientation changes. But I get it, with SDK development you want to make all developers happy.